# How to check isCallerInRole for local EJB/jndi in "JBoss 6"?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

In Jboss 5 we did like this to login and lookup a local EJB from a client within the same server:

```
private InitialContext getInitialContext(final String pPrinciple, final String pCredentials) throws NamingException {
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");

properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, pPrinciple);
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pCredentials);

return new InitialContext(properties);
}
...
MyEjbLocal myEjbLocal (MyEjbLocal)initialContext.lookup("some_jndi_string");
```

On the server side we had some code like:

```
@Resource
protected SessionContext sessionContext;
...
boolean isInRole = sessionContext.isCallerInRole( "myRole" );
```

In Jboss 6 how would you do the same?

Best regards and happy new year!
/Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution from the client.

```
public Properties getRemoteNamingProperties()
{
    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();

    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");

    // User added with add-user.sh 
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "myuser");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "!234Qwer");

    jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true); 
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "strong");

    return jndiProps;
}

...
private String jndiName = "ejbtest-app/ejbtest-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/StatelessBean!se.albinoni.ejbtest.stateless.StatelessBeanRemote";

...

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext( getRemoteNamingProperties() );

Object object = ctx.lookup( jndiName );
```

And at the serverside

```
boolean isInRole = sessionContext.isCallerInRole( "myRole" );
```

Think that is it, hope I have not have forgot anything.
Best regards
Fredrik